# Reducing algebraic fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{ 9,009x^{4/3}y^2 - 7,007x^{7/3}y }{ 4,004x^{1/3}y }$$

$$\frac{ 1,001x^{4/3}y (9y - 7x^1) }{ 4(1,001)x^{1/3}y }$$

$$\frac{ x(9y - 7x) }{ 4 }$$

How is it ${ 7x }$ it looks like it should be ${ 7x^{4/3} }$. Look at the top one, where it says four-thirds and seven-thirds, how does that play out? When you have to cancel out four-thirds with one-thirds.

Comment: use closed brackets {} when the super- or subscript is more than one character long.

Comment: Please, Clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^{a + b} = x^ax^b$, $x^{7/3} = x^{4/3 + 3/3} = x^{4/3}x^{3/3} = x^{4/3}x$.

Since $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a - b}$, $\dfrac{x^{4/3}}{x^{1/3}} = x^{4/3 - 1/3} = x^{3/3} = x$.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at just the numerator:

$$9,009x^{4/3}y^2-7,007x^{7/3}y$$
$$1,001x^{4/3}y(9y-7x^{3/3})$$

But $7x^{3/3}=7x^1=7x$, so

$$1,001x^{4/3}y(9y-7x)$$

Comment: Wrong, cause you have to cancel out the bottom expression with the top. Which is four-thirds - one-thirds.

Comment: If so, how does it stay the same(4/3).

Comment: @W.Zlacki  Ethan is certainly not wrong.  Notice that he stated that he is looking at just the numerator.

Comment: Sorry ethan didn't see that